# How to have a custom newline in PDF converted in XML (PDFminer)?

Tags: python, xml, pdf, pdfminer

I have this PDF document: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Kmq4kD2Xai7w9KAROIJZ-6baCKjHA5H/view?usp=sharing

And I converted it in XML with PDFminer. Problem is, I want to have a custom newline every time there are those longer spaces, for instance:

[image: screenshot PDF first paragraph]

in the first line, I want to have a newline before the "1" because there is a longer space:

> *Titolo* Il Causidico] *sps.* a Don Rodrigo `[BIG SPACE]` 1 sventura] *sps.* a mi-

I tried setting custom LAparams out, but I don't know how to achieve this. My code so far is:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter,TextConverter,XMLConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io

def convert(case, pdfpath, targetfilepath, pages=100):
    if not pages: pagenums = set();
    else:         pagenums = set(pages);
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    caching = True
    word_margin = 1
    laparams2 = LAParams(all_texts=True, detect_vertical=True,
                      line_overlap=0.5, char_margin=1000.0, #set char_margin to a large number
                      line_margin=0.5, word_margin=0.5,
                      boxes_flow=0.5)

    if case == 'text':
        output = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    if case == 'HTML':
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = HTMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    if case == 'XML':
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = XMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams= laparams2)

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(pdfpath, 'rb')

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    convertedPDF = output.getvalue()

    infile.close(); converter.close(); output.close()

    convertedFile = open(targetfilepath, 'wb')
    convertedFile.write(convertedPDF)
    convertedFile.close()

print(convert('XML', 'fel_split2.pdf', 'fe2.xml', pages=None))
```

See snippet of the output I get [here](https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/PoPqaeP) (otherwise it would be too long).

The result XML for the first line (non-essential information removed) looks like this:

```
<pages>
   <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315">
      <textbox id="1" bbox="44.614,554.008,58.101,564.246">
         <textline bbox="44.614,554.008,58.101,564.246">
            <text bbox="44.614,554.008,49.369,564.246">2</text>
            <text bbox="49.268,554.008,54.022,564.246">4</text>
            <text bbox="53.922,554.008,58.101,564.246">a</text>
            <text />
         </textline>
      </textbox>
      <textbox id="6" bbox="68.031,502.428,372.824,566.366">
         <textline bbox="68.031,553.628,372.759,566.366">
            <text bbox="68.031,553.639,76.375,566.366">T</text>
            <text bbox="76.231,553.639,79.479,566.366">i</text>
            <text bbox="79.334,553.639,83.161,566.366">t</text>
            <text bbox="83.017,553.639,88.112,566.366">o</text>
            <text bbox="87.968,553.639,91.216,566.366">l</text>
            <text bbox="91.071,553.639,96.167,566.366">o</text>
            <text bbox="99.311,553.628,104.406,566.110">I</text>
            <text bbox="104.261,553.628,107.510,566.110">l</text>
            <text bbox="107.365,553.628,110.269,566.110" />
            <text bbox="110.658,553.628,119.002,566.110">C</text>
            <text bbox="118.857,553.628,123.953,566.110">a</text>
            <text bbox="123.808,553.628,130.183,566.110">u</text>
            <text bbox="130.038,553.628,134.555,566.110">s</text>
            <text bbox="134.410,553.628,137.659,566.110">i</text>
            <text bbox="137.514,553.628,143.889,566.110">d</text>
            <text bbox="143.744,553.628,146.993,566.110">i</text>
            <text bbox="146.848,553.628,151.943,566.110">c</text>
            <text bbox="151.799,553.628,157.595,566.110">o</text>
            <text bbox="157.450,553.628,161.277,566.110">]</text>
            <text bbox="161.132,553.628,164.036,566.110" />
            <text bbox="164.417,553.639,168.244,566.366">s</text>
            <text bbox="168.099,553.639,173.895,566.366">p</text>
            <text bbox="173.751,553.639,177.578,566.366">s</text>
            <text bbox="176.966,553.639,180.215,566.366">.</text>
            <text bbox="180.070,553.639,182.974,566.366" />
            <text bbox="183.363,553.639,189.159,566.366">a</text>
            <text bbox="192.314,553.628,201.937,566.110">D</text>
            <text bbox="201.793,553.628,207.589,566.110">o</text>
            <text bbox="207.444,553.628,213.819,566.110">n</text>
            <text bbox="213.674,553.628,216.578,566.110" />
            <text bbox="216.967,553.628,225.311,566.110">R</text>
            <text bbox="225.166,553.628,230.962,566.110">o</text>
            <text bbox="230.818,553.628,237.192,566.110">d</text>
            <text bbox="237.048,553.628,241.565,566.110">r</text>
            <text bbox="241.420,553.628,244.668,566.110">i</text>
            <text bbox="244.524,553.628,250.320,566.110">g</text>
            <text bbox="250.064,553.628,255.860,566.110">o</text>
            <text />
            <text bbox="272.661,554.072,277.415,564.757">1</text>
            <text bbox="280.592,553.628,285.109,566.110">s</text>
            <text bbox="284.964,553.628,290.760,566.110">v</text>
            <text bbox="290.382,553.628,295.477,566.110">e</text>
            <text bbox="295.333,553.628,301.707,566.110">n</text>
            <text bbox="301.563,553.628,305.390,566.110">t</text>
            <text bbox="305.245,553.628,311.620,566.110">u</text>
            <text bbox="311.475,553.628,315.992,566.110">r</text>
            <text bbox="315.847,553.628,320.942,566.110">a</text>
            <text bbox="320.798,553.628,324.625,566.110">]</text>
            <text bbox="324.480,553.628,327.384,566.110" />
            <text bbox="327.763,553.639,331.590,566.366">s</text>
            <text bbox="331.445,553.639,337.241,566.366">p</text>
            <text bbox="337.097,553.639,340.924,566.366">s</text>
            <text bbox="340.312,553.639,343.560,566.366">.</text>
            <text bbox="343.416,553.639,346.319,566.366" />
            <text bbox="346.709,553.639,352.505,566.366">a</text>
            <text bbox="355.660,553.628,365.283,566.110">m</text>
            <text bbox="365.139,553.628,368.387,566.110">i</text>
            <text bbox="368.242,553.628,372.759,566.110">-</text>
            <text />
         </textline>
      </textbox>
   </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet of XML this creates for the first paragraph?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/PoPqaeP . Added it in the question as well. Codepen because otherwise it would be too long!

Comment: You can see that the XML only contains letters, each letter is individually placed in a bounding box (four coordinates, top-left and bottom-right). Do you want to add a newline in the XML? That would mean recalculating *every* bounding box that follows, complete with new word distribution per line and new pagination, I'd say that's extremely hard. Or do you want to extract the plain text only, and add newlines there?

Comment: I want to extract the plain text and have a line break every time there is that big space instead of the actual newline, I don’t know how to identify it though because it is not preserved in the final XML. I would need to keep the tags as well

Comment: As I said, each character has a bounding box that denotes its position, so the information is preserved. You can use this information to determine characters that are on the same line, but who have a larger-than-usual gap to the preceding character.

Comment: I tried with LAparams, it seems like what I need to increase is word param, but it didn’t work. Maybe I’m looking at the wrong one?

Comment: Not sure, I don't know enough about PDFminer to tell. I've been looking at solving this using XSLT, but I'm beginning to think that this might be a waste of time. I don't think I can help, sorry.

Comment: Here is what I've been trying - it breaks lines at the right points, but it does not arrange paragraph numbers (24a, 24b, etc) sensibly. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepL/1

Comment: thank you, this is great! Sorry for my ignorance, the code you created is not in Python- where should I insert it?

Comment: No, the code I created is XSLT. It's a language designed to convert XML to something else - e.g. into plain text, like here, but HTML or differently structured XML could also be the output. There are tools for running XSLT code in Python (I would recommend lxml), but be warned, XSLT has a learning curve attached to it.

Comment: Maybe you are better off when you work with the XML and recreate the same logic in Python itself: For each `<text>` on each `<textline>`, calculate the distance to the previous `<text>` box. Depending on that distance, print newline or space value, then print the character. This should be easier to manage than trying to learn XSLT for this.

Comment: Problem with that approach is, that it completely ignores layout in the input XML and strictly outputs the characters in the order they appear in the XML. This could result in janky output e.g. for complex layouts like tables, multi-column text, paragraph numbers, footnotes... Those are things that PDFminer might do a better job at.

Comment: I see. Well, with a few quick trials I see your approach with XSLT is really good and might work in my case, only I'm wondering how can I say not to create a newline when there is a hyphen at the end of the line (thing you did) but where there is no newline, create a newline?

Comment: How about: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepL/2 - but this was the last follow-up question I'll take on this matter. I can only encourage you to re-create the logic in Python, it's not complicated, and you will have much greater control over code you wrote yourself and understand.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: No worries. Have a great Easter Monday. :)